# Why show Read contact security warning?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I develop SMS & Call reader apps.
after this apps install. when incoming call then show

[image]

my menifest file like below:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <!-- Declaration that this app is usable on phones with Bluetooth Low Energy. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />
```

When i click allow then ok, otherwise deny 18 s .

i want when incoming call then not come this window, so should be auto works. 
How to remove window programmatic ally. or what are give permission in androidMenifest file . for that remove window.

Comment: Do you get this on an emulator, or on any other device? I am not aware that this dialog appears as part of standard Android. For example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners) reads contacts and does not display that dialog on a Nexus 4.

Comment: i test on android device.

Comment: "i test on android device" -- yes, I can tell that from the screenshot. I will ask again: do you get this dialog on an emulator, or on **any other device** than the one that you tested? If this only occurs on your device, then you will need to contact your device manufacturer or ROM mod supplier.